# How to edit a woocommerce hook

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to find what a woocommerce hook actually *does*, how it is defined, but at the same time trying to write my question generically enough that an answer might help others with similar questions.

My product has a couple of attributes, so the page currently displays:

```
>MY GREAT PRODUCT
>Price from: £x
>long winded description about how great it is - long winded description about how great it is - long winded description about how great it is.
>Attribute selection box 1
>Attribute selection box 2
>Price & Add To Cart Button
```

Great so far, but I'm also running the extension Woocommerce Product Add-Ons, which offers a choice of two additional configurations, so now its:

```
>MY GREAT PRODUCT
>Price from: £x
>long winded description about how great it is - long winded description about how great it is - long winded description about how great it is.
>Attribute selection box 1
>Attribute selection box 2
>Product Add-On 1
>Product Add-On 2
>Price & Add To Cart Button
```

Not so great, because when the customer selects the Attributes he still can't see a price unless he scrolls down the page past the product add-ons. So, finally, here's what I'm TRYING to do:

```
>MY GREAT PRODUCT
>Price from: £x
>long winded description about how great it is - long winded description about how great it is - long winded description about how great it is.
>Attribute selection box 1
>Attribute selection box 2
>**Price**
>Product Add-On 1
>Product Add-On 2
>Price & Add To Cart Button
```

Okay, so I've found that the hook I'm after is 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', and I want to edit it to do nothing more than take a copy of the price shown at the bottom of the page, and place it further up the page after the attributes box. Can I find a file anywhere which defines what happens when the woocommerce_template_single_excerpt action is called? Can I heck!

Comment: For situations like this I usually use Notepad++ or another text editor that has a "find in files" feature to search for that hook across all of the WooCommerce files.

Comment: Thanks Ennui, that's EXACTLY what I did (okay, I used Grep rather than Notepad), and I came up with three instances of woocommerce_template_single_excerpt, but it doesn't help :(

Comment: can you show code you got ?